# s/mime v3 with M2Crypto

Tags: python, m2crypto, smime

I would like to send a mail with a s/mime v3 attachment through SMTP.

The excellent HOWTO below describes the procedure in detail for s/mime v2.
http://sandbox.rulemaker.net/ngps/m2/howto.smime.html

I would greatly appreciate any help in doing the same for s/mime v3.

Arye.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about v3, but some updated info...

The new location for that howto is at http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/doc/howto.smime.html. Note that it is still for v2. There are also some smime tests at http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/test_smime.py

Comment: That is https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/blob/master/tests/test_smime.py these days, SVN is dead.